# Mysql query error: Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

I use vertx java to build an app and writing tests for mysql queries. I can successful get results before but after I modified my.cnf because of other stuffs. I cannot no long get returned results but "Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly". I searched google, but I cannot figure out exactly where is wrong and how to fix it.
I would post my.cnf file:

```
[client]
port    = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock
# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock 
nice    = 0
syslog

[mysqld]
# Basic Settings
port = 3306
user      = root
pid-file  = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid 
socket    = /tmp/mysql.sock
port      = 3306
basedir   = /usr/local/mysql/
datadir   = /usr/local/mysql/data
tmpdir    = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/local/mysql/share
skip-external-locking

# Engine
default-storage-engine  = InnoDB

# Listening IP
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

# Safety
max-connect-errors      = 1000000
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
skip-name-resolve
sysdate-is-now          = 1
innodb                  = FORCE
innodb-strict-mode      = 1
tls_version     = TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
wait_timeout            = 28800
interactive_timeout     = 10000

# Buffers
sort_buffer_size        = 4M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
join_buffer_size        = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 16M


# MyISAM
key-buffer-size         = 32M

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size          = 128M
max-heap-table-size     = 128M

# Bin logs
binlog-format           = ROW
log_bin         = /tmp/binlog
max_binlog_size         = 100M

server-id = 1 # randomize it incase of multiple servers

# InnoDB
innodb-buffer-pool-size         = 2048M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 8
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb-log-files-in-group       = 2
innodb-log-file-size            = 256M
innodb-file-per-table           = 1
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit  = 1
innodb-flush-method             = O_DIRECT

# With virtual synchrony redundancy, make write queries faster
innodb_doublewrite              = 1


# LOGGING
general_log_file                = /usr/local/mysql/mysql.log
log-error                       = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err
log-queries-not-using-indexes   = 1

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 64M

[isamchk]
key_buffer    = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with the configuration and what should I change? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this question is also there with PolarDB.

Comment: With PolarDB, just added an option for TCPKeepAlive = true, resolved.